# cypress command returns error in pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, nuxt.js, devops, cypress, github-actions

I have a CI setup using github Action/workflow to run cypress automated test everytime when a merge is done on the repo. The installation steps works fine however i run into issue when executing cypress command, let me show you the code.

**CI pipeline in .github/workflows**

```
name: Nuxt CI Pipeline

on:
  push:
    branches: [ CI-pipeline ]
  # pull_request:
  #   branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [ 14.x ]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - name: Make envfile
      uses: SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v1
      with:
        envkey_ENV: staging
        file_name: .env
    - run: npm ci
    - run: | 
        cd e2e
        ls -l
        npm ci
        npx cypress run
```

everything works fine until the last command `npx cypress run` where i get an error

```
Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
```

this same command works fine locally.I am not a devops guy so my information is very limited ,can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for some time turns out i was using cypress 8.7.0 which was causing the issue, i downgraded to cypress 8.5.0 and it started working, hope that helps anyone else having this issue

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer when possible!